# J1 waiver - Status changed to J1 within US (2004), never enrolled or particpated in the program and exited US

Tags: j1-visas

Status changed to J1 from F1 within US, never enrolled or particpated in the J1 program and exited US within 2 months of start date in 2004. Am I still subject to the 2-year home requirement?

Comment: 2004 ? That 2-year period is **long elapsed** if you are out of the US since then

Comment: @NicolasFormichella the requirement is not to remain outside the US but to remain inside the country of one's nationality.  If Jack10901090 is subject to the requirement and has not spent any time in that country since leaving the US then there are still two years to go, although a waiver may be available in some circumstances.  Also, not all J visa recipients are subject to the requirement, and most nonimmigrant visa applications are not affected by failing to meet the requirement.

Comment: Phoog & Nicolas, Thanks for the reply. Do I have to enroll and participate in the J1 program for the 2 year residency clause to trigger? I never enrolled or partcipated in the J1 program. Thanks.